# "Has" or "Have" after "Who" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm confused about using "has" or "have" after "who". For example:

1. I am a doctor who **have** confusion in using has or Have.
2. I am a engineer who **has** 4 year experience, degree in engineering and is
       available.

Will it vary depending on I or Who?

Comment: Also as a note: sentence 2 needs an *an* before engineer, an *a* before degree, and some clarification after *available*. Something like: _and is currently available for work._

Comment: _Who_ is third person, so even if it refers to a first- or second-person (_I, you_) it takes third-person agreement (singular _{-Z}_, plural _{-Zero}_) in the present tense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I am a **doctor** who **has** a treadmill.
>
> We are **doctors** who **have** an X-ray machine.
>
> I am a **professor** who **has** a tweed jacket.
>
> We are **professors** who **have** published three papers.

The verb **after** *who* should match the object **before** *who*.  (In the sentence structure you use, the **subject** [I/We] is independent of the **object** [professor/professors]):

> I know a **professor** who **has** grey hair.
>
> We know a **professor** who **has** mismatched socks.
>
> I know two **plumbers** who **have** leaky sinks.
>
> We saw three **mathematicians** who **have** proctectors in their pockets.

To quickly double-check your verb choice, simply remove the subject, predicate, and the *who*, and make sure it reads correctly:

> **"We know a doctor who have a new car,"** *becomes* **"A doctor have a new car."** (WRONG)
>
> **"We know the nurse who has a new sofa,"** *becomes* **"The nurse has a new sofa."** (RIGHT)

Answer (score 3):

In both your examples, the correct answer is **has**.

The word **has** refers to the **doctor** or **engineer**, not to **I**.

Answer (score -1):

It should be has in both the places. The second sentence should have an Engineer I feel