# "I who has" vs "I who have."

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What rules make “Remember me, who am your friend” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical)

Am aware it is correct to say `"I have written..."` and `"I am a doctor who has writen..."`

I have, however, severally come across the sentence `"I, Tertius, who have written..."`.
Shouldn't it be `"I, Tertius, who has written..."`?

[Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60182/has-or-have-after-who-in-a-sentence)

Comment: "Tertius" is parenthetical. The subject is the sentence is still "I" ...

Comment: http://bible.cc/romans/16-22.htm

Comment: The subject of the sentence is *I,* but the subject of the clause is *who.*

Comment: @Robusto. Doesn't the 'who' then logically warrant a 'has'?

Comment: The simple answer is that it does not. See the linked question.

Comment: @RegDwight. Thanks for the link. psmears answer is spot on.

Answer (score 3):

According to Fowler's Modern English Usage, "relatives take the person of their antecedents".  This means that "who" in the example is first person, not third person, because its antecedent is "I".  So "I, Tertius, who have written" is correct.