# Which has the correct usage?

Tags: verb-agreement

"You, my peer, who know no more than I" or "You, my peer, who knows no more than I"

I am leaning toward the first one, but the second one sounds more natural. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Logically it should be "You who know" regardless of any intervening words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I who has" vs "I who have."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65023/i-who-has-vs-i-who-have) '

<< According to Fowler's Modern English Usage, "relatives take the person of their antecedents". This means that "who" in the example is first person, not third person, because its antecedent is "I". So "I, Tertius, who have written" is correct. ... answered Apr 20 '12 ... user16269 >> Fowler looked at usage, recognising that logic and English usage often part company. / Here, 'You ... who know more than I' (the appositive takes the same case as 'You').